# How to add custom image to a button (dojo 1.7)

Tags: html, dojo

How do I add a custom image to a dojo button

here is the sample code for button without image

```
<div id="zoomin" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">
    <span>zoomin</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

These answers are close, but the style definition for your icon must include the following:

```
.myIcon {
  background-image: url(...);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set an icon class on your widget and then provide the image in css.

```
<div id="zoomin" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" iconClass="myIcon">
    <span>zoomin</span>
</div>

.myIcon {
  background-image:  url(...);
}
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/Button.html#change-the-icon

Comment: I also needed to add `width: 16px; and height: 16px;` to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

follow Craig's answer but to conform with 1.7+ and html standards, instead use

```
<div id="zoomin" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'myIcon'">
    <span>zoomin</span>
</div>
```

Or you can decide which through a function override

```
<div id="zoomin" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">
    <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="getIconClass">
         var regular = this.inherited(arguments);
         // this evaluation will allways be true, but here for sake of argument
         return (this.declaredClass == 'dijit.form.Button' ? "myButtonIcon" : regular);
    </script>
    <span>zoomin</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use dojo 1.10 and working with using `background-repeat:round`

```
<div id="zoomin" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" iconClass="myIcon">
<span>zoomin</span>
```

```
.myIcon {
 background-image:  url(...);
 background-repeat: round;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 text-align: center;
}
```